# Can I bring a decorative clay adorned goat skull to the US from Guatemala?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

Can I bring a decorative clay adorned goat skull to the US from Guatemala?
It is a real goat skull but covered with clay on the front and stones. It has its horns still as well. Is this legal or will I be fined if it was found?

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/116675/can-i-bring-a-painted-cow-skull-to-the-us-with-me-via-plane

Comment: You will not be fined if you declare it, even if it is ultimately not allowed. But you can be fined if you do not declare it. ALWAYS DECLARE.